# Одним запросом отправляем данные сразу в несколько таблиц

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Вопрос в теме топика, по существу. Есть какие варианты реализации?

Comment: Что Вы понимаете под словом "запрос"? Вызов query в php или запрос в mysql?

Comment: Вы не можете вставить в нескольких таблиц в одной команде MySQL. Однако, Вы можете использовать транзакции. [подробнее](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5178713/2546083)

Answer (score 4):

Сколько таблиц, столько запросов.
Можете написать хранимую процедуру, которая будет выполнять все эти запросы.
Тогда на клиенте будет один вызов.

Comment: Из списка обновляемых таблиц выделить главную, повесить на нее триггер, который бы вставлял данные в остальные таблицы сразу после того, как они были добавлены в главную.